# Which classes of drugs (filed by their pharmacology) induce a release of β-endorphin?

Tags: pharmacology, receptor

Which classes of drugs (filed by their binding sites) induce a release of β-endorphin? I know of agonists of the nAChRs and 5-HT<sub>1A</sub> and ethanol. Are there any others?

**Please cite journal articles with links to the respective articles**